# Displays correctly in Chrome, but not in Internet explorer 11

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

The site looks great in Chrome and Firefox:
 [image: Chrome-home] and [image: Chrome-about]

When I open the site in Internet Explorer, there is a huge gap on the right on my first two pages in the web-browser:

[image: Ie-home] [image: ie-about]

How can I remove the gap in the Internet Explorer?  Do I need to use a media query, specifically for internet explorer?  Is there a CSS hack or something?  I tried using a media query, but I wrote it incorrectly, and basically messed up my site. I removed it.  Oh yeah, is there a site I can use to test for Safari's web browser. I'm working on a PC. Any ideas would be much appreciated. :)

Updated!:  A fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5yon04ns/

```
<p> I have code in the fiddle</p>
```

Comment: post code if possible.

Comment: When it comes to CSS I prefer to use a CSS Franework like Twitter Bootstrap, 'cause it takes care of most browser differences. This is really a problem most of the times.

Comment: :( I'm using bootstrap.  Working on getting a fiddle up, so people can see my code.

Comment: Have the fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/5yon04ns/

Answer (score 0):

Try and add this to your css:

```
#header img { vertical-align: bottom }
```

It should be safe to add to your global css

Comment: It's hard to answer without anything to work with :/

Comment: and why you even try then?